# How to change character to ASCII in python without ord()

Tags: python

I know the function 'ord' can convert character to number.
but I just want to know how to convert without 'ord'

C can convert it, but is it impossible in Python ?

Comment: C does not convert characters to numbers. In C, characters are numbers. There is nothing to convert.

Comment: What is the point of not wanting to use `ord`, the right tool for the job?

Comment: I'm sorry about my bad English. I want to explain my situation but I can't : (

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encode a string as bytes, at which point you can access the representation of each character.  So you can do this:

```
print("a".encode()[0])
print("3".encode()[0])
print("#".encode()[0])
```

Result:

```
97
51
35
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use len() function to solve it
input("any value?")
print(len("value"))`input("any value you want") print(len("enter your value"))`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).